Derived functors from localization vs animation
I got a bit confused with the derived functors getting from the localization and the animation. More specifically, let $\mathcal{A}$ be an abelian category generated by compact projective objects $\mathcal{A}^{cp}$.
On one hand a left derived functor can be obtained from right Kan extend along the Dwyer-Kan localization of quasi-isomorphisms: $\mathcal{K}(\mathcal{A})\to \mathcal{D}(\mathcal{A})$.
On the other hand, one can also left Kan extend along the animation, i.e. $\mathcal{A}^{cp}\to \mathcal{P}_\Sigma(\mathcal{A}^{cp})=\mathcal{D}(\mathcal{A})_{\ge 0}$ where $\mathcal{P}_\Sigma(\mathcal{A}^{cp})$ is all the finite-products-preserving presheaves.
I understand that the localization is different from the animation since the former is a quotient and latter is an embedding etc, but is there any relation? This confuses me since one uses right Kan extension and the other one uses left Kan extension.

Just to be clear, when you say 'left derived functor', you mean there is some other abelian category $\mathcal B$ and a right exact functor $F \colon \mathcal A \to \mathcal B$ given, or some other setup?

@R.vanDobbendeBruyn Yes, let's assume this. Otherwise one can derive some nonadditive functor with the animation while doesn't make sense with the Dwyer-Kan localization.
